# Describe returned object type for a function which takes an array of object keys OR object containg values of string type

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `getParameters` which takes either array of parameter names, or object. The aim of the function is to load parameter values by provided parameter names. It returns a key-value object where key is parameter name and value - parameter value of string type.

These are how the function and the example of usage look like:

```
async function getParameters<T extends Array<string> | RecursiveObject>(
  paramNames: T,
): Promise<ParamValuesDictionary> {
  const paramNamesArr = !Array.isArray(paramNames)
    ? toFlatArray(paramNames)
    : paramNames as Array<string>;

  // Stub implementation of loading parameters
  const loadedParams: Parameter[] = paramNamesArr.map(name => ({
    name: name,
    val: `${name}_val`,
  }));
  
  const paramValues = convertToDictionary(loadedParams);
  return paramValues;
}

function toFlatArray(obj: RecursiveObject): string[] {
  let values: string[] = [];
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      values = values.concat(toFlatArray(value));
    } else {
      values.push(value);
    }
  }
  return values;
}

function convertToDictionary(
  parameters: Parameter[],
): ParamValuesDictionary {
  const paramValues: ParamValuesDictionary = parameters.reduce(
    (acc, { name, val }) => {
      acc[name] = val;
      return acc;
    },
    {} as ParamValuesDictionary,
  );
  return paramValues;
}

type Parameter = {
  name: string;
  val: string;
};
type RecursiveObject = {
  [key: string]: string | RecursiveObject;
};
type ParamValuesDictionary = { [name: string]: string };

getParameters(['a', 'b']).then(parameters => {
    console.log('Passed array:', parameters);
    /* OUTPUT:
    "Passed array:",  {
      "a": "a_val",
      "b": "b_val"
    } 
    */
});

getParameters({
    nameA: 'a',
    nameB: 'b',
    namesC: {
        nameC1: 'c1',
        nameC2: 'c2',
    },
}).then(parameters => {
    console.log('Passed object:', parameters);
    /* OUTPUT:
    "Passed object:",  {
      "a": "a_val",
      "b": "b_val",
      "c1": "c1_val",
      "c2": "c2_val"
    } 
    */
});
```

Right now the result of `getParameters` function is `ParamValuesDictionary`, which allows any string as a key. I would like to define strict keys of `ParamValuesDictionary` based on provided `paramNames` function argument. How should i change the type `ParamValuesDictionary` to apply this behavior? Appreciate any help.

[TS Playground link is available here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFNkAKwATsALb67EgA8AKjLgB7K4QAmIMAgsaWDRDJiqCNgB8MAD4wASrigJqqAG64A8gCMAVguTiAFACgYMAA4lyAOXK4QALhh0ANEYCUjgsXRlUIXDREpGQAasAANgh2ACKoUGiYJGCSAN4mMFCYQuaWZDYUILzEMAC8MACERcBgAHR+VWAGFsH5dm7ppgD8MMjoAGLhwMgNTbmtIO2mpo7N1rZcoDx81YLCohIA3EbpAPQ7MADKyAiaMKhkZuG4FBDIQxhY6HAw4ejA7Os5wZTU6ZkQ2Ve71w7CC5AcMDBFFYxAA2gBdUpfOYFIo1MjAMwGCC2UqSAxpKYwHEURwk3CuIkqCKOAAGABIUuSAL4AfWp4VplJgzLcbi2pj+WWQyNCESiXDK-zUxGQdHQsXiDySBiB7BBUImApgxHwSiwszFkTsW2Z20QKAePX6g2Gy0a6B0jnkimUai0uniHhgQhEYgRMEJL3wMA5EscvvWAbKCO1cHQxQM-2yYdwMCeMA9ehqqZABkd2j5gY6Z2eBmQYDMuAzqdKJTKAHIC3oG25i0TTLmkbmav8oENyzahiNU3ztaZmYxwv52x2e2YECAABYGUfjnnpM2mXXHYhYXOm81IJWYDKYGVyhVxBI44iNdKGn4QqE-BGub1QsLGkCKm9JWfJiKhpfuGkK5CBMTXsqd5Io+MIgDUursAgUC4MYRIGMAUBQM4gbErYuEcjybYlKkJamFhUCwuSiJlBy67bnqe4wJR67MtypgpJOiyfuKkEnreYDcvy6Q7vqooQSAh5GBWVZgd8MJIkG5IRmsYjahyql+tgppbLJaYukoICqBoOh6Ep6SwgA1rgYBaes8L2WI0hyAoRkmVm8S6TJlZprx36-tBYBKTA1G2E52COT6anYDyWxGHghC5E+Biwg2wANrhDaaA28JuDUyBLmwowKVQkpkUSyboFcNSvNgBgNkQID+OwLH2vYmWik+IlEjsABUmYAKp0AQw32CWABETUtW1-D2BNuGzkSE3ABNjgreyEQLeRMATZoa27Zom3hBNJaTiWfU7EYvLxYlL7wQSJbktwjjpZlT22AAQq9OUcfhBQAMKOEGHb-bgAMAIyvVAEPvaDpjkgDABM0NI3DUzsdd+WFcVcFlXiS1ngC1W4LV6D1Y1oAzc28Qdc4ePUD1Uz9UNI1jZN00gumZm0wtnE7StB0bRy22g3tQtHSLf2mBNMNCzDx2ix2stI-LSOK2dMAXVdN1GEAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8GoW) meet your needs?  If so I'll post an answer; otherwise what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @jcalz I'm checking it right now. I'll let you know when I finish

Comment: @jcalz It fully meets my expectations, thank you! Waiting for your answer to tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getParameters(parameters)` where `parameters` is of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be either a `RecursiveObject` or an array of `string`s, you want the value returned to be of an object types whose values are all `string` and whose keys are determined by `T` in a particular way.  Let's call that operation `Keys<T>`.  So `getParameters()`'s call signature should be

```
declare function getParameters<const T extends readonly string[] | RecursiveObject>(
  paramNames: T,
): Promise<{ [K in Keys<T>]: string }>;
```

Notice that I'm using [a `const` type parameter modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) on `T`; this asks the compiler to infer `T` from `getParameters(⋯)` as if the call had been `getParameters(⋯ as const)` with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  Otherwise a `parameters` value like `{k1: "v1"}` will be inferred as type `{k1: string}`, and that's not specific enough for your needs.  You want to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the property values, as if you had written `{k1: "v1"} as const`, resulting in the type `{readonly k1: "v1"}`.

And therefore I've changed `string[]` to `readonly string[]`.  The [`ReadonlyArray`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) type is less restrictive than the analogous [`Array`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) type, and since a `const` parameter will infer [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) for array literals, we will need to accept the wider type.

So now we have to define `Keys<T>`:

---

If `T` is some subtype of `RecursiveObject`, then `Keys<T>` should be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the string literal types of its leaf nodes.  So we'll need some recursive utility type `RecursiveObjectLeaves<T>` to compute that.  Otherwise `T` will be an array of string literal type elements, and we just want to grab the union of those elements by [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into `T` with `number`.  So `Keys<T>` will look like:

```
type Keys<T extends readonly string[] | RecursiveObject> =
  T extends RecursiveObject ? RecursiveObjectLeaves<T> :
  T extends readonly string[] ? T[number] : never
```

So now we have to define `RecursiveObjectLeaves<T>`.

---

Here's one way to compute it:

```
type RecursiveObjectLeaves<T> =
  T extends RecursiveObject ?
  { [K in keyof T]: RecursiveObjectLeaves<T[K]> }[keyof T]
  : Extract<T, string>
```

That's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `T` is an object; if so then we recursively call `RecursiveObjectLeaves` on each property and produce the union as a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  If not then `T` is a leaf node and we just return it... or rather `Extract<T, string>` using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler that this will be a `string`.

Let's test that:

```
type ROLTest = RecursiveObjectLeaves<{
  k1: "v1",
  k2: {
    k3: "v3",
    k4: "v4",
    k5: { k6: { k7: { k8: "v8" } } }
  }
}>;
// type ROLTest = "v1" | "v3" | "v4" | "v8"
```

Looks good.

---

So now we can put it all together (I'm just going to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the *implementation* of `getParameters()` to avoid compiler errors.  There's no way the compiler will ever understand that the value it returns will actually be of the type `Promise<{ [K in Keys<T>]: string }>` for generic `T`; it's just beyond the scope of its abilities to analyze.   So it will look like

```
async function getParameters<const T extends readonly string[] | RecursiveObject>(
  paramNames: T,
): Promise<{ [K in Keys<T>]: string }> {

  ⋯

  return paramValues as any;
}
```

And we can test how it behaves:

```
getParameters(['a', 'b']).
  then(parameters => {
    // ^? (parameter) parameters: { a: string; b: string; }
    console.log('Passed array:', parameters);
  });

getParameters({
  nameA: 'a',
  nameB: 'b',
  namesC: {
    nameC1: 'c1',
    nameC2: 'c2',
  },
}).then(parameters => {
  //    ^? (parameter) parameters: 
  //        { a: string; b: string; c1: string; c2: string; }
  console.log('Passed object:', parameters);
});
```

Looks good.  In the array case the compiler retrieves the literal types of `"a"` and `"b"` and uses them as the keys of the promised return value.  In the object case the compiler retrieves the literal types of `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c1"` and `"c2"` at the leaves of the nested property tree and uses them as the keys of the promised return value.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIHkBGAVgsADIQCG2qAPACoB8UAvAFBRS1QQAewEAdgBNUsBCgzZ8ReMCgB+NlADeUANoBpKOn5QA1hBAB7AGYcAugC5RSNFlyFiZShBq0NZxgF9V+o6dpmilYAorzI5DJ0ADRQqMDI2gDm9CwsoJCwOCS0LrJM1uJ2Uo4UVNRKiroAjFYARJhVtVGVAExWFezsugDMdZjdTYpdACx9w4OdegCs7XoAbLO6AOyLABx9q7VQntvbip4snvQA3CwA9GdQ6dAwWTlxzFD1jVAAPk-9W+-1428fm6lrlB1AZXFxeAJhFBkBRBIZ+AAbECxeJJVRmP5wGwSezSYCMVjsTg8PhCERYwqSBwyeQFWxUvFOMoMKAWRTEiFk6Gw+FIlEJfiJdG0tz8RAAWzwEGQGKs-Ag2GQqTOACooCxBAgEeQYVBjIh+DJ0PCoIkIMAAAo68ji83SmjweEPDmkqEw8hwxHIuICoUY94U+m44j0AAUijA1vFADkbS4rLRmgBKKwW5CGcXoVAQcpqTTaYGguj0Sz8pLbE4sFVnVLkVAgQ16g1Gk1my1Ru1oaiO-jO8GukTuz18n1o-10nHFGRhiNR2O21AJ5Op9OZ7O5jRaHQgkCuEtWUeCivKVLsHsPSPhGNx1AAQWQyEeAEJ7+EQAA6LOv8ggUOXm3zi4SZDLSwCGAAYtqwDfr+-7XguUB1hORTUsAwGTFYcGASISEwdQh7JKcijnrICKGB6ECCFaV6LlA1FxnwyDCvkWE3q+77iuQYChvwcbMIwoYdJ0vG2nKcbNJMmDkAiVgAAYACRKCJECeAA+lJCKyRJ2xJkmRFnk6shwQAatJiAuI8PaKsAtCGAAIugLa8cgv5kRRVFRqgemKDCwAoDoJlmRZSHkPwICnAcLD6oawDGjoYGQeQ0EPj+oaGIQViBpOqEptyHq8t6qKCsKQkIuaUAaeZtEEcxahmKc7DGIYj6hiRFVBVAJhQFOwDvpVLhpYQuknpM6CmKG1xdf1zBMPkADk6V4nNSYjZM7UIlVjz9ag749vASUTRBUEwaG-W6Q1nQ7BACLZqtklBTtYCIKgAAWp1Bd5kwHOw33cn5yA6NtEWpNFTlQFZ0o2fZjmxfCOq-rOV6drR9G2ox6LLnRUamRtLgOU58OrW1gW4yj2MPfjsPOciLEdoxO0woIiDwBA4aTKGETwDEKjKTEGk6fxd2dJzqjKRi+QaRdky+f5iHwPAUvbNp7BKDsSGozjVWU3F8PaZ9f2yyTVXA2k4DQKjnaPEJykHkViQXRptu+hFpxAllKF4lbig+AYTtJKWBGYmIQY9S7psZBrFMwzrLlW2oNtloKAd29sRFthb9Ohqoc3kHNMRzXgc1mEm76KMAL0CH+dP2oLQnsBcUAAHpyFAVdI4xK1wcjszkH7grHFAeB9-beyTOehhle+ZGJKGc1Wqg2aCIhKUgBYedQF39P6543ksOn1doIJijKbeVg53nx9xgAQmfhfacpqAAMLtCBymPzUUBzfAVQX5Mb9tJ-eALRf5K0OCXculdN41yYIwISDdOjN1blA5AncD60UUPAtayhELDwHkPROI9v64PBgAgiA9frj0ntPWe89F6dVQmvGIyCvIRW8kAA)